# Scrape site that has data saved as list

Tags: python, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the site data from url below, but it's saved in one massive list it seems. Was trying to put the columns I wanted in a list and concat to df but can't isolate by the column headers on the page (CF/60, xGF/60, etc). End result to have df resembling layout layout on the webpage. New at coding but I'm sure this could be written more efficiently. See code below:

```
import bs4, requests
import pandas as pd
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
chrome = ua.chrome


url = f'https://naturalstattrick.com/teamtable.php?fromseason=20212022&thruseason=20212022&stype=2&sit=sva&score=all&rate=y&team=all&loc=H&gpf=410&fd=&td='
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': chrome})
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', id = 'teams')
ts = pd.DataFrame()
dl = []
body = table.find_all('tbody')
for team in body:
    team_data = team.find_all('tr')
    for data in team_data:
        stats = data.find_all('td', class_='lh')
            print(stats)
    for d in team_data:
        numbers = d.find_all('td')
            for n in numbers:
                print(n.text)
```

Would someone be willing to help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [pandas.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) which can read all tables like content from url.

```py
import pandas as pd


url = f'https://naturalstattrick.com/teamtable.php?fromseason=20212022&thruseason=20212022&stype=2&sit=sva&score=all&rate=y&team=all&loc=H&gpf=410&fd=&td='
dfs = pd.read_html(url, index_col=0)
df = dfs[0]
```

```
print(df)

                     Team  GP   TOI/GP   W   L  OTL  ROW  Points  Point %  ...  LDSF%  LDGF/60  LDGA/60  LDGF%  LDSH%  LDSV%    SH%    SV%    PDO
1     Tampa Bay Lightning  29  47.4034  19   6    4   18      42    0.724  ...  49.98     0.38     0.40  48.75   3.57  96.25   8.43  92.55  1.010
2    Vegas Golden Knights  36  49.5505  20  13    3   19      43    0.597  ...  58.13     0.32     0.35  48.29   2.23  96.68   8.12  90.74  0.989
3     Toronto Maple Leafs  33  50.0242  24   7    2   23      50    0.758  ...  49.56     0.27     0.29  48.10   2.33  97.53   7.68  91.27  0.989
4     Washington Capitals  34  48.5299  16  13    5   14      37    0.544  ...  50.36     0.33     0.31  51.94   2.69  97.48   8.23  91.24  0.995
5      Colorado Avalanche  33  47.4298  26   4    3   24      55    0.833  ...  55.51     0.56     0.39  59.05   3.56  96.92   8.73  93.04  1.018
6         Edmonton Oilers  32  48.1698  20  12    0   17      40    0.625  ...  52.86     0.26     0.52  33.51   1.86  95.86   7.79  91.12  0.989
7          Buffalo Sabres  33  50.1535  12  16    5   10      29    0.439  ...  44.02     0.17     0.48  25.62   1.31  97.02   8.33  91.38  0.997
8         Ottawa Senators  34  48.7044  12  19    3   12      27    0.397  ...  49.99     0.34     0.26  56.07   2.51  98.03   6.71  91.95  0.987
9       Detroit Red Wings  34  48.4289  17  12    5   16      39    0.574  ...  46.62     0.35     0.41  46.09   2.98  96.96   9.21  90.61  0.998
10       Florida Panthers  32  48.0438  26   6    0   25      52    0.813  ...  58.29     0.44     0.27  61.81   3.08  97.34   9.41  91.42  1.008
11       New York Rangers  31  49.6167  22   6    3   19      47    0.758  ...  49.22     0.37     0.24  60.43   3.05  98.07   8.65  93.13  1.018
12    Carolina Hurricanes  33  47.0545  24   5    4   24      52    0.788  ...  59.27     0.46     0.31  59.42   2.88  97.14   7.85  92.86  1.007
13  Columbus Blue Jackets  34  48.9554  18  13    3   16      39    0.574  ...  44.54     0.49     0.72  40.38   4.14  95.09   9.69  90.33  1.000
14    Nashville Predators  31  46.7414  20  11    0   18      40    0.645  ...  50.35     0.21     0.39  34.77   1.67  96.82   8.29  93.10  1.014
15          Anaheim Ducks  34  47.6917  16  14    4   14      36    0.529  ...  49.46     0.33     0.46  41.55   2.86  96.06   7.21  91.67  0.989
16      Los Angeles Kings  35  48.0414  18  13    4   15      40    0.571  ...  55.52     0.21     0.11  66.61   1.57  99.02   6.76  91.66  0.984
17      New Jersey Devils  33  49.2258  16  14    3   14      35    0.530  ...  47.12     0.28     0.35  44.90   2.46  97.31   7.56  90.42  0.980
18    Philadelphia Flyers  34  48.7598  13  15    6   13      32    0.471  ...  47.42     0.38     0.41  47.84   2.90  97.15   8.27  91.56  0.998
19          Boston Bruins  32  47.5797  20  10    2   19      42    0.656  ...  58.72     0.31     0.52  37.54   1.92  95.46   6.47  89.47  0.959
20     Montreal Canadiens  33  48.4520  10  19    4    9      24    0.364  ...  47.83     0.29     0.47  38.02   2.31  96.55   6.70  91.05  0.977
21    Pittsburgh Penguins  33  48.8308  19   9    5   17      43    0.652  ...  52.20     0.19     0.31  37.51   1.43  97.40   7.96  92.09  1.000
22        San Jose Sharks  34  48.7069  16  14    4   14      36    0.529  ...  39.56     0.21     0.45  32.25   2.30  96.83   6.95  90.90  0.978
23         Calgary Flames  33  48.5475  21   6    6   20      48    0.727  ...  58.20     0.47     0.27  63.99   3.44  97.30   8.61  91.91  1.005
24        Arizona Coyotes  32  48.8130   9  22    1    9      19    0.297  ...  39.38     0.35     0.36  49.45   3.41  97.73   9.40  90.94  1.003
25     Chicago Blackhawks  32  48.2693  11  16    5   10      27    0.422  ...  44.82     0.32     0.49  39.45   2.64  96.71   7.11  90.80  0.979
26         Minnesota Wild  31  46.6710  23   7    1   21      47    0.758  ...  49.94     0.77     0.55  58.55   5.37  96.21   9.97  91.65  1.016
27          Winnipeg Jets  34  48.9397  19  13    2   18      40    0.588  ...  51.63     0.39     0.29  57.70   3.00  97.65   7.74  92.32  1.001
28           Dallas Stars  31  48.2016  21   9    1   20      43    0.694  ...  47.56     0.11     0.40  21.38   1.04  96.54   8.99  91.48  1.005
29         St Louis Blues  33  48.6293  20   9    4   19      44    0.667  ...  47.65     0.47     0.40  54.18   4.77  96.33  10.18  92.01  1.022
30         Seattle Kraken  32  48.1479  11  18    3   10      25    0.391  ...  47.02     0.55     0.57  49.01   4.74  95.62   8.19  89.43  0.976
31      Vancouver Canucks  32  48.7359  14  13    5   12      33    0.516  ...  52.24     0.35     0.08  81.75   2.65  99.35   6.47  93.90  1.004
32     New York Islanders  34  48.9333  17  13    4   17      38    0.559  ...  46.20     0.38     0.37  50.53   4.06  96.59   7.83  93.32  1.012

[32 rows x 71 columns]
```

Comment: Wow. Can't believe it was that simple. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mattias1990 **If your question is solved**, say thank you by ***accepting** the solution that is **best for your needs***. The **accept check** is below the up/down arrow at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. If you have a reputation of 15 or greater, you may also vote on the quality of an answer, with the up or down arrow. **Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question**. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for calling this out. I completed this request.